# Alpha options for Azure ACS (Kubernetes)

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-container-service

Is it possible to enabled Alpha API options for Azure ACS Kubernetes instances? If so how?

For example

```
--enable-custom-metrics=true
```

For horizontal auto scaling based on custom metrics

Comment: This is also useful for Cron based pods which also need the alpha extensions

Answer (score -2):

To maintain an SLA, clusters created by ACS limit the default use of alpha or beta features within Kubernetes.  To use more advanced features of ACS, visit https://github.com/Azure/acs-engine, and modify the kubelet yaml within the /parts directory.